# Setting ACL Google Cloud Storage via the PHP library

Tags: php, google-api-php-client

I am using the PHP library for Google API Storage. How do I set the acl parameter (to 'public-read' for example) when inserting a storage object, in order to make an object public via its URI?

I have tried this:

```
$gso = new \Google_Service_Storage_StorageObject();
$gso->setName($folderAndFileName);
$gso->setAcl('public-read');
```

but the use of setAcl doesn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's an easier way, but this should work:

```
$acl = new Google_Service_Storage_ObjectAccessControl();
$acl->setEntity('allUsers');
$acl->setRole('READER');
$acl->setBucket('<BUCKET-NAME>');
$acl->setObject('<OBJECT-NAME>');

// $storage being a valid Google_Service_Storage instance
$response = $storage->objectAccessControls->insert('<BUCKET-NAME>', '<OBJECT-NAME>', $acl);
```

You can see all the possible values [here](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1beta1/objectAccessControls).

Also, this requires the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control` scope when authenticating.

Comment: This worked, thanks! ->setBucket() and ->setObject() are not necessary to call. Thanks also for the note on the scope, which is needed in order to not get an error "Insufficient Permission".

Comment: Is there not a way to do it in one request ? object setAcl should work also !

Answer (score 0):

In order to set the access control for an individual request, you must do the following:

In order to make the file public, the role must be set as "OWNER" and entity as "allUsers"

Documentation can be found here: 
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control#predefined-project-private

```
$acl = new Google_Service_Storage_ObjectAccessControl();
$acl->setEntity('allUsers');
$acl->setRole('OWNER');
```

and then you must apply the ACL to storage object as follows:

```
$storObj = new Google_Service_Storage_StorageObject();
$storObj ->setAcl(array($acl));
```

The setAcl function requires an array as it parameter, therefore you add your access control object as the only element in an anonymous array